# Stackviewer iOS Application

Tags: app, ios, release

Stackviewer is a beautiful and easy-to-use custom Stack Overflow client where software developers of any kind can find answers to their everyday challenges. Browse through millions of questions with a variety of built-in filters and search options, learn from high-quality and information-packed answers, upvote the helpful content and downvote the irrelavent as you wish, quickly familirize yourself with a new tag, monitor your inbox and questions you've asked as well as favorite questions that might be useful in the future - all of that is possible with Stackviewer.

Download link:
[Stackviewer on App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackviewer/id1305547655?mt=8)

This iOS app was built for portfolio.

Comment: This app appears to no longer be available.